# liferay migration Alfresco

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, alfresco, alfresco-share

I wan't to migrate my Liferay 6.1 from filesystem to Alfresco.

When I introduce these parameters in portal-ext.properties:

```
dl.store.impl=com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.CMISStore
dl.store.cmis.credentials.username=admin
dl.store.cmis.credentials.password=admin
dl.store.cmis.repository.url=http://localhost:9080/alfresco/service/api/cmis
dl.store.cmis.system.root.dir=Liferay Home
```

The option CMIS in Administration panel-Migration dissapear.

If I select FileSystem, the console shows me this error

```
Exception in thread "liferay/convert_process-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.CMISStore$SessionHolder
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.CMISStore.<init>(CMISStore.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor111.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.StoreFactory.getInstance(StoreFactory.java:87)
    at com.liferay.portal.convert.ConvertDocumentLibrary.doConvert(ConvertDocumentLibrary.java:91)
    at com.liferay.portal.convert.ConvertProcess.convert(ConvertProcess.java:44)
    at com.liferay.portal.convert.messaging.ConvertProcessMessageListener.doReceive(ConvertProcessMessageListener.java:47)
    at com.liferay.portal.convert.messaging.ConvertProcessMessageListener.receive(ConvertProcessMessageListener.java:32)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:63)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.SerialDestination$1.run(SerialDestination.java:110)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:671)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:582)
```

Any Ideas?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You probably have all of your documents in a filesystem repository (or the default repository).

For migration you'll have to run Liferay with a setting that has all documents, e.g. before you change your portal-ext.properties to CMIS.

What you can and should do is to configure the access credentials to your CMIS installation, but don't update the `dl.store.impl` yet.

Now go to the Migration form in Server Administration (can't remember exactly, I have no admin access to Liferay currently), you can select CMIS as *the target* that you migrate to. Once migration has been done, shut down, change the value for `dl.store.impl` and start up. Make sure that nobody uploads new documents during the migration process.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, I tried also, but when I tried to access or upload a file, is giving me this error : 11:40:10,615 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-4][PortletServlet:115] javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.CMISStore$SessionHolder
javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.CMISStore$SessionHolder